# createDataFrame from List<Row> result throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1version.
I have a code something like below.

```
    val dataDs = ///have dataset

    val part_dataDs = dataDs.repartition(col("fieldX"));

    StructType schemaType = part_dataDs.schema();

    part_part_dataDs.foreachPartition(itr ->{

    Iterable<Row> rowIt = () -> itr;
    List<Row> objs = StreamSupport.stream(rowIt.spliterator(), false)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("inrow.length: " + objs.size());

    Dataset<Row> partitionData = sparkSession.createDataFrame(objs, schemaType);

    partitionData.show;
```

}

**Error :**

```
[Executor task launch worker for task 418] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 1.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 418)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:380)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to create a dataframe inside a `foreachPartition`? (That, btw, is not allowed)

Comment: `foreachPartition` (as well as `mapPartition`) gives you a list-iterator to the rows in the partitions. Maybe you are looking to use `foreach` rather that `foreachPartition`?

Comment: Ehm, I just had a look at the sample you supplied. There are several problems with the code you have written. Can you provide a simple version of the business logic you want to do? That will make it easier for us to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, you seem to be misunderstanding a few basic things. The two functions: `foreachPartition` and `mapPartition` operate on each partition in the dataset. The  `itr`-variable in your

```
part_part_dataDs.foreachPartition(itr -> ....
```

refers to an iterator for the partition. You can use this iterator to iterate over the list of rows like you would if it was a list of strings.

In principle, you could write something like this:

```
part_part_dataDs.foreachPartition(itr ->{
  itr.foreach(row -> {
    System.out.println(row.getString(0));
  })
})
```

although I have to stress that this piece of code make no sense at all. The `println` statement would executed on some random worker node, so it's not something you would see, unless you run on a single node. Also, this example should simply use `foreach` instead of `foreachPartition`, but as this appear to be a contrived toy example, I can't tell if you do indeed require `foreachPartition` or not.

Comment: Sounds more like you want the `rank` window function??

Comment: Using the `rank` window function will indeed cause data to be processed in parallel. Anyway, the questions you post here reveal a rather poor understanding of Spark and the best help I can offer, is to suggest that you take a step back and spend some time following some tutorials to improve your understanding of how Spark works. Once you have a better understanding of the Spark fundamentals, you will see why you are way off track with this solution attempt. Sorry...